# What's the difference between どうしたらいい and どうしていい?

Tags: word-choice

Particularly in the following phrases, what's the difference between [どうしたらいい](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%84) and [どうしていい](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%84)? The following both seem to mean something like "I don't know what to do":

> - どうしたらいいか分かりません
> - どうしていいか分かりません

Is there some difference between どうして and どうしたら which changes the nuance or meaning somehow?

Is どうしたらいいか分かりません stronger in meaning than どうしていいか分かりません?

Answer (score 5):

- どうしたらいい 'what I am supposed to do, what I should do'
- どうしていい 'what I am allowed to do, what I may do'

Answer (score 3):

Looking at it backwards...

> こうしたらいい
>   If I do this, good outcome.
>   こうしたらよくない
>   If I do this, bad outcome.

And...

> こうして(は)いい
>   I can do this (because it achieves a good outcome).
>   こうしてはだめ
>   I can't/shouldn't do this (because it achieves a bad outcome).

So it kind of sounds like...

> どうしたらいいか分かりません
>   I don't know what will achieve a good outcome.
>   どうしていいか分かりません
>   I don't know what I can possibly do. (OR...)
>   I can't figure out what I can/should do.

That's my best attempt at clearly capturing the difference between the two, but if you're still unsure, I do think that considering the feel of こうしたら？ versus こうしては？ can illuminate the difference somewhat.

I also feel like どうしたらいい is a little less immediate/urgent than どうしていい, but I'm not sure how to explain that difference well.

The difference is difficult to pinpoint, really...but I imagine it won't make a great difference most of the time, either.